# MySQL Join Clause Algorithm

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a php library to manipulate arrays. It working like a mysql engine. Users will can join , order and do any mysql functions to their arrays. But I am stuck in join clause. How MySQL join clause actually works? Is they using for loops?

Here is my approach.

```
foreach ($this->joins as $join) {
            $table = $join->getTable();

            /** @var DataSet $joiningDataSet */
            $joiningDataSet = $this->__globalizeDataSet($table->getName(),$table->__getDataSet());
            $mainDataSetCount = $mainDataSet->getCount();
            $joiningDataSetCount = $joiningDataSet->getCount();
            for ($i=0; $i < $mainDataSetCount; $i++) { 
                $mainRow = $mainDataSet->getByIndex($i);
                for ($j=0; $j < $joiningDataSetCount; $j++) { 

                    $joiningRow = $joiningDataSet->getByIndex($j);
                    $tmpDataSet = $this->makeNewSetByDualRows($mainRow,$joiningRow);
                    $on = $join->getOnCluase();
                    $matched = $on->setDataSet($tmpDataSet)->execute(0);
                    if($matched){
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

But how do I push data sets to main data set when join modes(LEFT,INNER,RIGHT..) changing? I don't want codes. I want only an idea. IS my approach is correct or wrong?

[Here](https://github.com/whizsid/arraybase/blob/0ee11d5d97f446c92f6c78294856f5c85a21fe7f/src/Query/Traits/Joinable.php#L93) is the stuck point in my project.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: looks like you are trying to join 2 datasets via PHP. Joining is a job for the database: it's faster and uses fewer resources likely. Also saves you time on coding this in raw php.

Comment: You are asking us to guess the internal workings of mysql?

Comment: @tvgriek But when programmers getting data from other resources(API, With two big queies) they don't want to use temporary DB tables with the help of this library.

Comment: The open version of MySQL is, well, open. You can study the sources to know how it works. But that's way too broad to be discussed here.

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes. I want the fastest and most accurate way.

Comment: Perhaps you could start here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/guided-tour.html

Comment: Finally I have finished my package. github.com/whizsid/arraybase